# Hang after bootloader, looking for device

Tags: boot, systemd, partition, boot-loader

I tried to copy my bootable partition (e.g. `sda1`) from a removable drive to my internal drive (e.g. at `sdb2`) for an openSUSE 42.3 installation. It took me a bit of time to correct the bootloader entries referencing `/dev/sda1`, but eventually, I thought I had updated all of the references to indicate the correct partition, and also in `/etc/fstab`.

But, when I select the entry in the bootloader, after the initial booting messages, the system hangs with a message like:

```
A start job is running for dev-sda2.device (9s / no limit)
```

The start job continues to run until I forcibly power off the system.

I have double and triple-checked the bootloader (`/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`) and `/etc/fstab` files to ensure that they are referencing the partition's new location, or Label, or UUID. Why would my system still have problems detecting the drive/device?

Comment: This message is generated by systemd, not grub or kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I believe openSUSE references the UUIDs of the partitions in its boot code, so I subsequently had to re-make the initialization image with `mkinitrd -f`.

Not being able to boot into the operating system on this partition, I had to mount the partition and then perform this operation in a `chroot` jail:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount -B /dev /mnt/dev
mount -B /sys /mnt/sys
mount -B /proc /mnt/proc
chroot /mnt
mkinitrd -f
yast bootloader # Possibly necessary, though I only needed the mkinitrd call
```